# How Inheritance works with mixins in dart

Tags: dart

I have the following code:

```dart
class A {
  void m() {
    print("hello");
  }
}

mixin B {
  void m() {
    print("mixin class b");
  }
}

class C extends A with B {
  void m() {
    print("m of c");
    super.m();
  }
}

void main() {
  C cc = C();
  cc.m();
}
```

Here when I write `super.m()` it is referring to the `mixin` class rather than `m()` of class `A`, why? Which exactly is its superclass referenced by super.
How can I then call `m()` of class `A` from `C`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get the `m` method on `A` in your example. The reason is by using mixins you are telling the compiler you want to extend `A` but please insert all methods from `B` even if one of the methods overrides an existing one. So after compile, the compiled class of `C` ends up not even containing `A.m`.

There are some details about this behavior in this older article and with some explanation about why this is the case: https://medium.com/flutter-community/https-medium-com-shubhamhackzz-dart-for-flutter-mixins-in-dart-f8bb10a3d341